# How to create php pages dynamically from xml nodes, and then link to that page - simplexml - php

Tags: javascript, php, xml

As the title says i want to create dynamicaly new pages with all the content from my xml and then link those pages to a read more link. The code that i have is this one:

```
<?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('$url');
?>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
   $name = $xml->hotel[$i]->hotel['hotelname'];
   $desc = $xml->hotel[$i]->description;
   $file_name = 'usercontent'.$i.'.php';
   $post = 
   '
    <li>
        <a href=$file_name>'.$name.'</a>
        <p>'.$desc.'</p>
    </li>
    ';
     file_put_contents($file_name, $post);      
 echo $post;
}
```

But how can i link dynamicaly to the files created ? And i have pictures too that i must take from the xml nodes. Any help is apreciated. New to php and i am trying to make this script work for 2 weeks now.

The xml looks like this:

```
<hotels>
<hotel hotelcode="ADORA" hotelname="ADORA GOLF RESORT HOTEL" country="TURKEY" location="BELEK">
 <description> bla blah</description>
<images>
<image url="http://46.108.32.196/hotel_images/ADORA___1559.jpg"/>
<image url="http://46.108.32.196/hotel_images/ADORA___1560.jpg"/>
</images>
</hotel>
```

Haven't thought of any logic because i don't know where to start. 
Thank you.

EDIT 1:
here is a codepad test : http://codepad.viper-7.com/9gj3C0 with my script and with some modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following. `$file_name` must be relative url;

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($xml->hotels as $hotel) {
    $name = $hotel->attributes()->hotelname;
    $desc = $hotel->description;
    $file_name = 'usercontent'.$hotel->hotelcode.'.php';

    foreach($hotel->images as $image) {
        $imgUrl = $image->attributes()->url;
    }

    $post = '
    <li>
        <a href=$file_name>'.$name.'</a>
        <p>'.$desc.'</p>
        <p><img src="'.$imgUrl.'"/></p>
    </li>
    ';
}

file_put_contents($file_name, $post);      
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. After testing this code and added echo $post; the page shows blank. Wonder Why ?

Comment: Where should i check ? i have replaced the echo with print_r($post); and nothing is showing up.

Comment: put this `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of page, and see error on page

Comment: What is the value of `$url` ?

Comment: $url = "http://resurse.fibula.ro/parteneri/xmlhotels.php?prices=true&location=belek";

Answer (score 0):

Use the file name, or insert your xml file location in the simple_load_file() function instead of a variable.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file(path/to/your/file.xml);
foreach ($xml->hotels as $hotel) {
$name = $hotel->attributes()->hotelname;
$desc = $hotel->description;
$file_name = 'usercontent'.$hotel->hotelcode.'.php';

foreach($hotel->images as $image) {
    $imgUrl = $image->attributes()->url;
}

$post = '
<li>
    <a href=$file_name>'.$name.'</a>
    <p>'.$desc.'</p>
    <p><img src="'.$imgUrl.'"/></p>
</li>
';
}
file_put_contents($file_name, $post);      
}
?>
```